# If $\frac{\sin2x}{\cos x}-1=0$, find $x$ given $\ \frac{\pi}{2}\le x\le\pi$ (cancelling out vs multiplying out the $\cos x$)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

To solve the equation
$$\frac{\sin2x}{\cos x}-1=0 \tag1$$
I manipulated it into the following:
$$\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos x}-1=0 \tag2$$
Then, by multiplying $\cos x$ out, I obtained:
$$2\sin x\cos x-\cos x=0 \tag3$$
However, according to the answers I was supposed to cancel out the $\cos x$ which results in
$$2\sin x-1=0 \tag4$$ Thus, I myself attained the answers $\frac{5\pi}{6},\ \frac{\pi}{2}$, whilst the answer booklet merely had $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ .

I do not understand the logic behind cancelling out the $\cos x$ - I thought we were supposed to maximise the number of answers obtained by multiplying out rather than cancelling.

Any help clearing up my confusion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that $x=\pi/2$ is NOT a solution of your original equation. Be careful when multiplying both sides of an equation by a non constant factor, because this operation can introduce new values for the variable $x$ that don't satisfy the equation you started with.

Comment: @Carnby Thanks for your input, but unfortunately I am still quite confused. Could you perhaps please explain why π/2 is not a solution in another way?

Comment: @qwerty just plug the value $x=\pi/2$ into your original equation and see that it is not satisfied.  As a simpler (and rather silly) example, imagine that you want to solve $x-1=1$. If you multiply both sides by $x$, you get $x^{2}-x=x$, and this equation has two solutions, $x=2$ and $x=0$. But this latter is NOT a solution of $x-1=1$. It appears because we have multiplied our first equation by a non constant factor $x$, and this introduces an additional value of $x$.

Comment: @qwerty More generally, imagine that you want to solve $f(x)=g(x)$, or equivalently, $f(x)-g(x)=0$. Now, let's suppose that you need to multiply this equation by a non constant factor $h(x)$; what you are now solving is $h(x)(f(x)-g(x))=0$, and this is satisfied by those values of $x$ such that $f(x)-g(x)=0$ (the equation you're interested in) OR $h(x)=0$. But not all values of $x$ making $h(x)=0$ will make $f(x)-g(x)=0$, so all those values are irrelevant for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that $$\frac{\sin2x}{\cos x}-1=0$$
It is **implicit** or *already implied* that $\cos x \ne 0$.

In general, given a fraction, it is implicit that $\text{Denominator} \ne0$ as otherwise the term would become *not defined/undefined/indeterminate* (as it now contains $1/0$).

So, in the end, you are required to reject all those values of $x$ for which $\cos x=0$. 
In your case, $\pi/2$ must be rejected. Only $5\pi/6$ is valid.

Comment: Thanks for this! Just clarifying, does that mean my method was otherwise completely correct (i.e. multiplying out the cos $x$ )?

Comment: @qwerty yes, absolutely. The approach of "multiplying rather than cancelling" is a better way as then you don't accidently lose out on any possible answers. It's just that in cases such as yours where there is an implicit condition or if there is an explicit condition (say, like $x>\pi/4$) then, at the end, we're supposed to check if our values satisfy them. Finally, in scenarios such as $x^2=x$, you may solve as $x^2-x=0$ OR as $x=1, x=0$. In former, chances of mistake (of losing out a value) are $0$. In latter, when we cancel, we simultaneously *adjust/account* for it.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion is due to the violation of *equivalence* conditions between mathematical steps.

---

> *Problem statement*:
> $$\frac{\sin2x}{\cos x}-1=0$$
> where,  $\frac {\pi}{2}\leqslant x\leqslant\pi$.

$\rm Step-1.$

$$\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos x}-1=0$$

There is no issue here. Because: $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$.

$\rm Step-2.$

$$2\sin x\cos x-\cos x=0$$

We want to analyze this step.  When we multiply both side of the equation by $\cos x$, we should do this under the restriction $\cos x≠0$.  So why?

1. No matter what mathematical operation we apply, before we start solving the equation $\frac{\sin2x}{\cos x}-1=0$, it is necessary to state that $\cos x≠0$.  Because, we can never make the denominator $0$.
2. Applying the multiplication we have:
   $$\cos x \left(\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos x}-1\right)=0\cdot \cos x$$
   This is essentially equivalent to:
   $$\cos x \cdot \frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos x}-\cos x=0$$

Then, we can easily reduce the last equation to the following equivalent equation:

$$\begin{align}\frac {\cos x}{\cos x} \cdot \left(2\sin x\cos x\right)-\cos x=0\end{align}$$

Think about: if $\cos x=0$, can we write $\frac {\cos x}{\cos x}=\frac 00=1$ ?

Since $\cos x$ can not equal to $0$, then the multiplication under the restriction $\cos x≠0$, (even if $\cos x$ is not in the denominator) doesn't produce roots that are called [extraneous roots](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions) in mathematics.

> Therefore, the *original* equation $\frac{\sin2x}{\cos x}-1=0$ is equivalent to the *derived* equation $2\sin x\cos x-\cos x=0$, if and only if, when $\cos x≠0$.

---

The possible correct solution can be reached with the following $2$ ways:

$\require {cancel}$

$$\begin{align}&\frac{\sin2x}{\cos x}-1=0\\
\iff &\frac {2\sin x\cdot\cancel{ {\color{#c00}{\cos x}}}}{\cancel{\color{#c00}{{\cos x}}}}-1=0\\
\iff &2\sin x-1=0,\thinspace \cos x≠0\\
\iff &\sin x=\frac 12,\thinspace\cos x≠0\end{align}$$

or

$$\begin{align}&\frac{\sin2x}{\cos x}-1=0\\
\iff &\frac {2\sin x\cos x}{\cos x}-1=0\\
\iff &\frac {2\sin x\cos x-\cos x}{\cos x}=0.\end{align}$$

Then we know that,  $$\frac {A(x)}{B(x)}=0\iff A(x)=0\wedge B(x)≠0.$$

Therefore, we have:

$$2\sin x\cos x-\cos x=0,\thinspace\cos x≠0$$

This leads to:

$$\begin{align}&\cos x\left( 2\sin x-1\right)=0,\thinspace\cos x≠0\\
\iff &2\sin x-1=0,\thinspace\cos x≠0\\
\iff &\sin x=\frac 12,\thinspace \cos x≠0.\end{align}$$

Finally, under the restriction $\frac {\pi}{2}\leqslant x\leqslant\pi$, we obtain:

$$\sin x=\frac 12\wedge x≠\frac {\pi}{2}$$

Thus, indeed the answer is $x=\frac {5\pi}{6}$.